# How to route a query string in a codeigniter Search?

Tags: codeigniter, routes, query-string, codeigniter-routing

I have a question with route a query string.

I'm trying to route with codeigniter a search. I have some parameters for each search, first a input text field, for a title or a description. Second, I have categories like, Utilities, Games, Exercise... Third, a platform, like, IOS, WP, Android.. and also the page.

I would like to see the route like:

/page/3, or

/page/3/search/whatever  or

/cat/Games    or

/cat/Games/search/battelfield or

/page/1/cat/games/search/battelfield or

/search/whatever or something like that.

I am using this code for the function in the model:

```
enter code here

 function getAppBy($categ, $page, $str, $platform) {

    $perpage = 16;
    $offset = ($page-1)*$perpage;


    $this->db->select('app.id');
    $this->db->from('t_yp_app_category cat, t_yp_user_apps app');
    if ($categ != "") {
        $this->db->where("cat.name =", $categ);
    } if ($str != "") {
        $this->db->like('app.yp_title', '%' . $str . '%');
        $this->db->like('app.yp_description', '%' . $str . '%');
    }if ($platform != "") {
        $this->db->like('app.yp_platforms', '%' . $platform . '%');
    }

    $this->db->limit($perpage,$offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    //FIN SELECT
    if (sizeof($result) > 0) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

enter code here
```

Thank you. If I havent explained well, let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//www.mysite.com/search/sometitle/puzzle/android/4
$route['search/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'search/getAppby/$1/$2/$3'; //default without offset, which is why offset defaults to 0
$route['search/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'search/getAppby/$1/$2/$3/$4'; //default with offset
//You may want to use some regex rather than wildcards ie:(:any)

public function getAppBy($input, $category, $platform, $offset=0){}
```

Comment: How to do if it is like localhost/test/5/?lat=27.6799225&lng=85.31890150000004&query=a&filter=distance

Comment: @Philip can you answer to krishna comment as I m having the same issue.